# best way to accumulate data in google charts api?

Tags: json, google-visualization

I need to accumulate data from multiple tables, which indeed requires multiple queries for fetching the data from different tables. As per my research I found the format for google charts api (line charts) is like this:

```
[
          ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],
          ['2004',  1000,      400],
          ['2005',  1170,      460],
          ['2006',  660,       1120],
          ['2007',  1030,      540]
        ]
```

how can I update the array in PHP to make is similar to this. In details, 
I mean to say I have queries that fetch data and I am able to make it like a json (key, value) thing. for eg,

```
{"0":0,"1":0,"2":0,"3":0,"4":4,"5":2,"6":0,"7":2,"8":0,"9":0,"10":17,"11":0,"12":0}
```

Where key represents the month and data is representing the corresponding values for that month. 
there would be couple of more like this, and I need to accumulate them together so that the data fit into the format requried for google line charts api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a bunch of objects with key:value pairs representing different data series, and your keys are the same in all objects, you can do something like this:

```
$rows = array(array('Month', 'data series 1', 'data series 2' /* etc... */));
foreach ($dataArray1 as $key => $val) {
    $rows[] = array($key, $dataArray1[$key], $dataArray2[$key] /* etc... */);
}
```

If you are running SQL queries to fetch the data, however, it is probably easier to do a table join to get all of the data in one query rather than multiple queries.